# How use includes method with array of arrays?

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript, and would like to check if an element exists in an array of arrays.

Here is an example:

```
var array =[[1,5,6],[2,3],[5,8,9]];
```

How check for example `6` exists in `array` ?

Comment: May be `var exists = array.some(x => x.includes(6))`

Comment: Thank you it solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let exists;

array.forEach(x => {
  if (x.includes(6)) exists = true; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use reusable function. Try this on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvxp6hyd/)

```
var array =[[1,5,6],[2,3],[5,8,9]];

function checkAvailability(arr, val) {
  return arr.some(function(arrVal) {
    return arrVal.includes(val);
  });
}

checkAvailability(array, 6); // true
checkAvailability(array, 12) // false
```

Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for `Array.some()`;

Hint:

> some() was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as such
>   it may not be present in all implementations of the standard. You can
>   work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of
>   your scripts, allowing use of some() in implementations which do not
>   natively support it. This algorithm is exactly the one specified in
>   ECMA-262, 5th edition, assuming Object and TypeError have their
>   original values and that fun.call evaluates to the original value of
>   Function.prototype.call().

Polyfill:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.17
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.17
if (!Array.prototype.some) {
  Array.prototype.some = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined');
    }

    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;

    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t && fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };
}
```